# Call a method on any field of a specific type c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I know that is easy with reflection to find a property of a specific name and call a method on it

```
var fields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                            BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x=>x.FieldType == typeof(IMyType));
    
foreach (var field in fields)
{
      var myMethod = typeof(ITenantService).GetMethod("MyMethod");
      var test = myMethod ?.Invoke(field, new object[]
      {
             myParameter
      });
}
```

This doesnt work because field is FieldInfo. GetFieldValue is a string which is of no use

How can I do this please?

What I am aiming for in the end is for something that given a type I find all of the fields that have a field of a specific type, and call my method on that field

Cheers

Paul

Comment: You want to pass the the property value as a parameter to method?

Comment: Can you show a non-reflection example?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay except you were passing the wrong argument (`field`) to the first parameter of Invoke method of `MethodInfo` class.

In the first argument, it needs an object to call this method (`PrintMyName`) from.

After finding the target type, we can easily use `Activator.CreateInstance()`, it will return an object, which we can use in the next step while calling the method.

The `Invoke()` method of the `MethodInfo` class needs us to provide an object to call this method.

This is a working example of what you are seeking:

```
using System.Reflection;

public class MySubClass
{
    public void PrintMyName(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello" + name);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private MySubClass myFirstSubClass;
    private MySubClass mySecondSubClass;

    public void GetFieldsTypesAndRunTheirMethods()
    {
        var fields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                           BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(MySubClass));

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var myMethod = field.FieldType.GetMethod("PrintMyName");
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(field.FieldType);
            myMethod?.Invoke(obj, new object[]{"james bond"});
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new MyClass().GetFieldsTypesAndRunTheirMethods();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Use the `FieldType` property of `FieldInfo` class to get the type of the field, so we can create an instance from it by knowing its type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this when I get home but at a glance I want to use existing objects not create new ones

Comment: I cant use this approach because it is creating new objects, I want to get to the original objects?